# Running install.jar crreated from izpack gives me no such method exception

Tags: java, izpack

Built an install.jar using Izpack 5.0.0-beta10 and compiler.bat

When I try and run it using java -jar install.jar I get

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.izforge.izpack.util.file.FileUtils.close(Ljava/io/Closeable;)V
        at com.izforge.izpack.installer.container.impl.EventFiller.readObject(EventFiller.java:154)
        at com.izforge.izpack.installer.container.impl.EventFiller.loadCustomData(EventFiller.java:62)
        at com.izforge.izpack.installer.container.impl.InstallerContainer.fillContainer(InstallerContainer.java:98)
        at com.izforge.izpack.core.container.AbstractContainer.initBindings(AbstractContainer.java:25)
        at com.izforge.izpack.installer.bootstrap.InstallerGui$1.run(InstallerGui.java:47)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

This on Windows I have JAVA_HOME set to Java 7 jdk, and typing java -version from the command prompt also gives me Java 7

I can build and run the same install.xml with Izpack 4.3.5 no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be depending on a different version of izpack-util to that of the installer.

In any case, you're running an old version of 5.0. I'd suggest downloading the latest snapshot from the [repository](https://nexus.codehaus.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/codehaus/izpack/izpack-dist/5.0.0-beta11-SNAPSHOT/)

Comment: You maybe onto something with izpack-util but I dont see it, as I dont have any izpack stuff on my path and I build and run from same location

Comment: Hmm, just tried it again a month later and it worked no problem, but no idea what has changed.

Comment: Oopps, no it doesnt work I was using an old install.jar created with izpack 4.3.5, Ixpack 5 doesnt put the install.jar in the same place as  the install.xml which is a little confusing.